# Alert Javascript as return response of action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, alert

how can i do, for example, i create a user in users.cshtml view, that it validates to ActionResult Create(RegisterModel um) and if its all ok, i want to return at users.cshtml but always with one javascript alert or similar, with the value of a variable from the action. Can i do this one?

I have it this in my view..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Crear Usuario</legend>

     <div class="editor-label">
        Username:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Password:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
        Repite Password:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And this in my controller action..

```
public ActionResult Create(RegisterModel um)
{

    if (um.Password == um.ConfirmPassword)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        Membership.CreateUser(um.UserName, um.Password, um.Email, um.PasswordAnswer, um.PasswordQuestion, true, null, out createStatus);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            var alert = MembershipCreateStatus.Success.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));

            var alert = ErrorCodeToString(createStatus);
        }
    }
        //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO RETURN TO /ADMIN/USERS BUT WITH AN ALERT WITH CONTAINING THE VALUE OF alert IN A JAVASCRIPT OR SIMILAR ALERT WINDOW

    return RedirectToAction("Users", "Admin"); ???????
```

Can i do it something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could store the message inside `TempData` just before redirecting to the `Users` action:

```
TempData["message"] = "some message that you want to display";
return RedirectToAction("Users", "Admin");
```

and then inside the `Users.cshtml` view (which is returned by the `Users` action to which you redirected) test for the presence of this message and display an `alert`:

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["message"])));
    </script>
}
```

Comment: thank you darin, instead of trying yours, i wasted some hours, i have posted answer below using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to show error in same view, instead of trying darin's answer i tried other like [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1957583.aspx?Show+alert+from+controller+in+its+View) using `ViewBag` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089917/how-to-return-partial-view-of-another-controller-by-controller) to show error in another page by returning `Partial View`

finally i tried using `TempData`, to maintain the message during post, here i am showing error using bootstrap

**action method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegDetail(User_table usob, FormCollection col)
{
 // some other code here
if (!sqlReader.HasRows)
{
TempData["message"] = "Contains some message";
return RedirectToAction("Registration");
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**my registration view:**

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
<link href="~/css/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/boostrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-danger">

<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>

<strong style="width:12px">Error!</strong> Thats wrong code no, try entering correct!

</div>

}
```

if you need to explore more using Tempdata you can check [this](http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/) where Mr.James explains using bootstrap messages, hope helps someone