# Multiple mvc Asp.Net MVC controller in single page application in mvc using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I have selected **Single page application(MVC,Web api)** in visual studio. Then create two Asp.net MVC controllers with the name of **HomeController** and **AdminController**.

In Asp.net MVC HomeController, i have 2 partial view first one is **ShowStudents** and second one is **showTeachers**.
In AdminController, i have 2 partial view first one to **AddStudent** and second one **AddTeachers**.

In **_Layout.html** page i have initialize my angular app `ng-app="myApp"` and in Index.cshtml view of HomeController add the `ng-view` directive to display partial view data(of ShowStudents and ShowTeachers).Its woking fine but now the question is

**how to display partial view(AddStudent and AddTeacher) of AdminController in Asp.net MVC Single page application?**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089917/how-to-return-partial-view-of-another-controller-by-controller

Comment: no in my Single page application, i have ng-view in HomeController Index view and i am not be able to bind other controller view in that ng-view

Comment: @ADyson  can you help me?

Comment: did you read the question i posted the the link to? Did nothing there help you?

Comment: @ADyson yes i have readed.. but my requirement is in Single page application to add multiple Asp.Net MVC Controller and calling their views(cshtml) in single ng-View directive of angularJS which is totally different  from that

Comment: so you can't use @Html.Partial to inject the view data? If you mean you're trying to do it dynamically then you probably need to use ajax to return the HTML from the partial.

Comment: @ADyson no i am using     return PartialView("Post");   inn my Asp.net MVC controller and its working fine. i have used ng-view directive of angularJS to bind all view one by one its working fine for all view of same controller only but i want to call another controller view in it which is not working

Comment: and an example like `return PartialView("~/views/ABC/XXX.cshtml", zyxmodel);` as per that answer I linked you to doesn't work?

Comment: @ADyson Its not working for me because i have two Asp.Net MVC controller  and call second controller view through their action method in first one controll and then bind it in `ng-view` directive in Index.chtml of angularJS .... but  ng-view directive in Index.cshtml view  only allow their own controller action methods only

Comment: so you're chaining controller actions together? I don't know if that's the cause of your problem but it doesn't sound like a very good design in general.

Comment: yes @ADyson and i am new in Single page application in asp.net mvc . i am trying to create large Single page application using Asp.net MVC and angularJS where i can create multiple Asp.net mvc Controllers and view .. is it possible?

Comment: if you just want a single page app, you might be better using one single MVC view which simply loads the page, and then some Web API controllers which return JSON data to your app from the server. Then define all your views using angular.

Comment: ok but is it possble with multiple asp.net MVC controllers and views in angularJS single page application?

Comment: i don't know, i've never tried. But I'd have thought it was simpler to define them in angular - angular has its own view system, you might as well use that