# how to display returned PartialView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I work on my mvc5 project.

I have this action method:

```
    public PartialViewResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="result"></div>
```

I need to access to the action type above and to put the returned result in div.

How can I implement it?Can I use any HTML helpers?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial
This might be usefull.

Comment: @DimitriBosteels I tryed this  @Html.RenderPartial(""); but it didnt helped me because I need to access to the action and not to the view.

Comment: You need to put the name of the action as first parameter (Login in your case I think) And you can pass your model as second parameter if you need to pass data

Comment: Check this post if you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089917/how-to-return-partial-view-of-another-controller-by-controller

Comment: use `@Html.Action()` or `@{ Html.RenderAction(); }` if you want to call a server method that returns a partial view - e.g `@Html.Action("Login", yourControllerName, new { returnUrl = someValue })`